# Post request working fine in Postman but returning 404 status code in android studio

Tags: android, api, rest, android-studio, kotlin

[image]Im trying to hit a REST api to register user on the server with POST request ..... when i hit the api using postman it will return response but inside android studio api is called but didn't returned the response.... I don't know that Where I'm  doing mistake.

**Api Interface**

```
interface Api {

    @POST("https://blaklif.com/v1/")
    fun regsiterUser(@Body userRequest: UserRequest):Call<ResiteredData>

    @POST("https://blaklif.com/v1/")
    fun loginUser(@Body userRequest: UserRequest):Call<ModifiedLoginResponse>

    @POST("https://blaklif.com/v1/")
    fun getUPostList(@Body paramsUserList: ParamsUserList):Call<ResponseList>
}
```

**Functions i used to hit the api**

> Fetch data will get the user Request Body and return a object which will further send it into the
> api body(as request).....

```
  signUpButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            saveUser(fetch_data())

        })
} // onCreate ends
 fun fetch_data() : UserRequest {
          val userRequest: UserRequest =
              UserRequest()
          val email = email.text
          val password = password.text
          val fullname = fullname.text
    
  /// these feilds are using for sending the data into the spi body ///
        userRequest.setUser_name(fullname.toString())
        userRequest.setPassword(password.toString())
        userRequest.setEmail_address(email.toString())
        userRequest.setAndroid_token("APA91bEAfoucYYgXO_" +
                "t1ENfJvY2hRXdH5SUFjFDAZL2kgjes_jYyo15tPPI0fYHkL" +
                "TmuagQbHAth5dmA6uPdpB_dhJhcwt47t9vR2ChldINDmJ5vGmc" +
                "WcOyUg5Uqc0cR0lflqD3oaoRs")
        userRequest.setDevice_type(0)

        return userRequest
    }
   ////  save user function called the api using Retrofit with  userRequest Body //
         fun saveUser(userRequest: UserRequest){
             val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
             httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

             //  val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
             val okHttpClient1 = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)

             val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                 .baseUrl("https://blaklif.com/v1/")
                 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                 .client(okHttpClient1.build())
                 .build()

             val api = retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
             api.regsiterUser(userRequest).enqueue(object : Callback<ResiteredData> {
                 override fun onResponse(
                     call: Call<ResiteredData>,
                     response: Response<ResiteredData>,
                 ) { 
                      /// here i'm getting the response code  ->>>>> 404
                    Log.d("UserRegistered","Registered")
                     val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,DashBoardActivity::class.java)
                     startActivity(intent)

                 }

                 override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResiteredData>, t: Throwable) {
                     Log.d("UserFailed ->","Failed")
            
                 }
             })

         }
```

**Model Class**

```
data class ResiteredData(
    val `data`: Data,
    val success: Boolean,
    val text: String
)
data class Data(
    val android_token: String,
    val bio: String,
    val device_type: String,
    val email: String,
    val fb_id: String,
    val gender: String,
    val google_plus_id: String,
    val ios_token: Any,
    val is_active: String,
    val is_public: String,
    val lif: String,
    val live_in: String,
    val location: String,
    val login_type: String,
    val native_from: String,
    val password: String,
    val phone_number: String,
    val profile: String,
    val qb_dialog_id: String,
    val qb_id: String,
    val tagline: String,
    val token: String,
    val u_id: String,
    val username: String,
    val website: String
)
```

**Server Response in PostMan**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "u_id": "322",
        "username": "shivam",
        "profile": "",
        "email": "intelhybrid3123@gmail.com",
        "location": "",
        "website": "",
        "lif": "",
        "phone_number": "",
        "gender": "",
        "bio": "",
        "tagline": "",
        "live_in": "",
        "native_from": "",
        "password": "d386cef906fde4ccff27cfcdc8385ba4",
        "token": "uQK4dhZCtDjpHwSz0qfoPArN9",
        "device_type": "0",
        "android_token": "APA91bEAfoucYYgXO_t1ENfJvY2hRXdH5SUFjFDAZL2kgjes_jYyo15tPPI0fYHkLTmuagQbHAth5dmA6uPdpB_dhJhcwt47t9vR2ChldINDmJ5vGmcWcOyUg5Uqc0cR0lflqD3oaoRs",
        "ios_token": null,
        "login_type": "user",
        "fb_id": "",
        "google_plus_id": "",
        "qb_id": "",
        "qb_dialog_id": "",
        "is_public": "1",
        "is_active": "1"
    },
    "text": "Your account register successfully."
}
```

I try to change the model class but it didn't workout.

Comment: In Postman you use `https://blaklif.com/v1/register`, but in Retrofit you access `https://blaklif.com/v1/`.

Comment: In interface use only v1/register and in base URL only add https://blaklif.com/

Answer (score 1):

you should set subUrl inside API interface like this:

```
interface Api {

    @POST("register")
    fun regsiterUser(@Body userRequest: UserRequest):Call<ResiteredData>

    @POST(*SET SUB URL*)
    fun loginUser(@Body userRequest: UserRequest):Call<ModifiedLoginResponse>

    @POST(*SET SUB URL*)
    fun getUPostList(@Body paramsUserList: ParamsUserList):Call<ResponseList>
}
```

BASE_URL **+** SUB_URL=ACTULA_URL

**EXAMPLE**

https://blaklif.com/v1/ **+** register = https://blaklif.com/v1/register

Comment: Thnaks for help!! status code is 200 now, but I'm still not getting the data in response

Comment: maybe exist an issue in data models. not equal with API JSON response.